# osx server, windows client, running emacs opens it on server not client

Tags: ssh, x11, osx, emacs, putty

I've installed emacsformacosx on my OSX box.  I'd like to shove my macmini in a data center and run it headless.  I've gotten x-windows working.  If I run xeyes, it displays on my Windows 7 client.  Emacs works from the command line on the osx box.  However, if I start up emacs from the windows client, it pops it up on the server instead of the client.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an X11 display server running on your Windows workstation? If yes, do you have X11 forwarding enabled on putty?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs is a console application thus it starts in putty directly. If you want it to open in a new terminal window then you have to execute terminal and pass emacs command to it. Assuming you have xterm:

```
$ xterm -e emacs
```

Comment: I don't want to open it in a new terminal.  I want to open it in an x-windows window, as happens if I run xeyes.

Comment: Yes but emacs is console application? Or are you using some gui variant of emacs like `xemacs`? That would open it in a separate window.