# Start emacs client on Windows XServer

Tags: x11, emacs, xemacs

I have managed to get X-forwarding running to use xemacs on my local Windows machine.
Now I can start **xemacs** from the ssh terminal to my remote linux machine. This results in xemacs running in a window on my windows machine:

[image]

I would very much prefer to use **emacs** in a windows window, but what happens is that emacs opens in terminal mode.

Since this works for xemacs I would assume some setting is wrong on the linux machine.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994898/running-emacs-in-graphics-mode-on-remote-server) it seems setting up x-forwarding is sufficient.

I am stuck - can you give me a hint how to get this working?

---

Edit: the solution in the duplicate question opens a window which contains again the **text only version** of emacs. After

> sudo yum install emacs

the nicer graphical version opens correctly!

Comment: Could you please clarify which machine, if any is running Unix or Linux? Are you connecting to a Windows machine from a *nix one? What do you mean by "client window"? Please [edit] and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @terdon is this better?

Comment: Better but veering off topic I'm afraid. Your question seems to be about configuring a Windows machine and not the *nix side but I'm not sure. How are you connecting to the Linux machine?

Comment: @terdon I am connecting via putty ssh. Since xemacs works, I would assume there is some switch to get emacs to behave similarly to xemacs?

Comment: @terdon I found the answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126367/osx-server-windows-client-running-emacs-opens-it-on-server-not-client?rq=1

Comment: @terdon Should I delete the question or flag it as duplicate?

Comment: Ah! OK, now I understand. Please add the output of `readlink -f /usr/bin/emacs` (run from the Linux machine) to your question. Also tell us what distribution the Linux machine is running. Do you have a graphical version of emacs installed?

Comment: Oh, if that solved your issue, I'll close it as a dupe. Make sure you actually have a graphical emacs installed though, you might not. Leave me a comment here if it doesn't work and I'll reopen.

Comment: @terdon Your comments helped me find the answer, thank you!

Comment: @terdon You were right, the real solution was > sudo yum install emacs